# Adding BouncyCastle Dependency bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar to iText Java Application in Eclipse Fails

Tags: eclipse, jar, itext

I am using iText version 5.5.2 and trying to implement passwords to stop users from editing our generated static XFA pdf reports.  I don't think I am able to flatten a static XFA PDF Form (so correct me if I am wrong). My only option at this point, would be to use iText's ability to password protect the form in a way where users will not have to worry about putting in a password to edit the form, but still be able to view it.

Anyway here is the problem. According to the Lowagie's book, implementing a password requires the use of the bouncastle APIs. To do this right, I implemented the  iText-5.5.2. Searching through this iText dependencies, I found that the maven POM for iText-5.5.2 shows that I have a need a couple of bouncycastle jars:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.49</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
   <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
   <version>1.49</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

When I add these to my project within eclipse of (IBM's CICS Explorer), eclipse complains as follows:

Description Resource Path Location Type Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/nuo3545/jars/bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar' in project 'jCicsPdfUtility' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    jCicsPdfUtility Build path  Build Path Problem

So this indicates that the jar being added (bcprov-jdk15on-1.49.jar) to my project properties libraries or class path is bad, or not being recognized. Is there a solution for this?

Q. Are bouncycastle jars still an issue or broken for usage within iText? What is my recourse of fix to this problem?

Any help or direction with this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: 1. You can flatten XFA with iText' XFA Worker which is a closed source add-on for iText. 2. We can't reproduce the problem and we build our own code using the POM and run tests that require BouncyCastle. Reading the error message, it seems as if the problem is caused by the BouncyCastle jar: it's as if your app doesn't have access to it or as if the file is corrupted (not a valid ZIP file). There is no indication that the problem is related to iText. My guess: something went wrong when downloading the dependencies. Solution: start anew from scratch.

Comment: Hi Bruno, Thanks for the response. I am in the process getting your APIs licensed and in the process of investigating the use of XFAWorker. I know that I have defined the following dependencies in place.

Comment: - xfaworker-5.5.2.jar
- xmlworker-5.5.2.jar 
- itext-licensekey-1.0.3.jar
- iText-5.5.2.jar

Comment: OK, but did you test your BouncyCastle jar? The best way to test if the jar was downloaded correctly, is to write some code that uses BouncyCastle but not iText. If the problem persists, you know that you should replace the corrupted BouncyCastle jar.